# Performance issue while using cloud service WepAPI for another cloud service application

Tags: performance, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

Please find our application configuration.

Deployment server : Azure web role 
Architecture : Multi-Tier
Presentation  & Service Tier :  Azure VM -  MVC application & Asp.Net Web API
Database Tier : Azure VM  - SQL server 2012

Both presentation and service running in same VM but separate application in IIS. This is working fine.

When scalability is concern, we have migrated our application into azure web role.

We have bought two cloud services and created two web role for each one(Presentation & Service)

And found application performance is too slow when comparing with previous implementation.

And we found the cause is,

- Previously both presentation and Service in same VM and shared data using Internal IP address with in the machine itself.
- But now, since both application in different cloud service, sharing information over internet using Public IP address(sharing between cloud service) took time.

Can multiple website(both presentation & service) hosted in single web role and information will be shared using internal IP?  Can anyone advice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add more then a single web role to a cloud service and you will avoid the public IP problem you described.
In your CloudService project find the “Roles” node 
Right click on it and add another web role

Regarding the IP communication between machines on the same cloud service, you will need to set a static IP to your instance if you don’t the IP address might change if a the machine restarts for some reason